# Create Multiple Slides from a List with Common Template

Tags: powerpoint, batch-processing

I have created a certificate design with powerpoint. 
Now I have to create 100+ copies of it... each with a different name (the recipent).

I was wondering if there was an easy way to do it...

I can have the list of names in excel or txt.

I am open to other ideas as well, like changing the slide into an images and batch processing it in a simple way

Answer (score 2):

You may also try out *SlideMight*, a tool for merging hierarchical data with PowerPoint templates. SlideMight supports iteration over data, to generate slides or to populate tables. There is more functionality, but you don't seem to need that. SlideMight is in fact a coding system, like mail merge for Word is.

Input data format is at this time just JSON; you would need to convert your Excel sheets first, e.g. using this [Excel to JSON](https://store.office.com/en-za/excel-to-json-WA104380263.aspx) add-in for Excel.

There are versions for Windows and Mac OS X.
More information is at [www.SlideMight.com](http://www.SlideMight.com)

Disclaimer:

I am the owner of Delftware Technology, the company that developed SlideMight.
And I am one of the developers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that really belongs in SuperUser, not StackOverflow (which is intended for coding questions, not software how-to-use questions).

But ...

Save your names to a plain notepad TXT file, one name per line.

Start PowerPoint, choose File, Open and point to your TXT file (you may force the matter by choosing *.* in Files of type:

Apply whatever template you like to the result.

I have a commercial add-in that'll do this and quite a bit more, but from your description, you don't need it.